# Neid ohne Missgunst

Tags: word-usage

Der Begriff "[Neid](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Neid)" bedeutet, dass man jemand anderem seinen Besitz missgönnt und diesen für sich selbst haben will. Gibt es ein Wort, das ausdrückt, dass man den Besitz des anderen für sich selbst möchte ("Ich will auch ein iPhone"), aber ohne die zusätzliche Bedeutung, der andere möge den Besitz verlieren?

Comment: Sowas nennt man schlichtweg *Wunsch*. Den Teil drückst du durch "Ich will/möchte" aus. Deine Gunst, also dass du es dem anderen nicht nehmen willst, betonst du durch das Wort "auch". Aber als Kombi, in einem Wort, gibt's das nicht. Synonyme zu Wunsch im Sinne von etw. haben wollen (reduziert auf Gegenstände) sind z.B. *Begierde* oder *Gier*. Diese Wörter drücken aber nur einen stärkere Willen aus, bzw. letzteres hat zumal noch eine negative Konnotation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Wunsch**

Was den Neid auszeichnet, ist ja weniger, dass man etwas möchte, als dass man es dem anderen nicht gönnt. Die Missgunst ist das definierende Moment des Neides und die Motivation für das Habenwollen. Fällt diese weg, verschwindet auch das Wollen: Was der Nachbar nicht hat, das brauche ich auch nicht.

Wenn man ohne Missgunst etwas will, das man beim Nachbarn sieht, ist das ein Wunsch. Man kann ja nur etwas wollen, von dem man weiß, dass es existiert. Der Nachbar ist in diesem Fall nur die Quelle der Information. Für den Wunsch ist es gleichgültig, ob er entsteht, weil ich etwas bei meinem Nächsten oder in der Werbung gesehen habe.

„Woa, hat der ein tolles Auto! Der hat so viel Spaß damit, das freut mich für ihn. So ein Auto wünsche ich mir auch. Wenn ich es mir nur leisten könnte! Aber immerhin leiht er es mir manchmal aus. Toller Typ, mein Nachbar.“

Comment: So habe ich das noch nie betrachtet - für mich hingen diese Konzepte automatisch zusammen, weil der Wunsch durch die Beobachtung eines anderen ausgelöst wurde, wie beim Neid.

Answer (score 0):

Neid ist ein Impuls, der einen überkommt, und der nicht danach fragt, ob der andere, der etwas hat, was Du auch gerne hättest, das verdient hat. Er fragt auch nicht ob es ein Unikat ist, das Du nur haben kannst wenn er es nicht hat oder ob Du Dir morgen auch eins kaufen gehen kannst.

Das kann eine Reaktion auf den Neid sein, dass Du räsonierst und es dem anderen gönnst und Dich besänftigst mit der Möglichkeit unabhängig von ihm ein eigenes Objekt zu erlangen.

Man kann auch neidisch sein auf die Fähigkeit eines anderen, die man nach menschlichem Ermessen nie erreichen wird, Pässe spielen wie Péle, Gitarre wie Hendrix - man kann es dem anderen gar nicht wegnehmen. Das Gefühl ist dennoch Neid.

Der Wunsch dagegen kann unabhängig von einem anderen sein, der etwas hat.